# How to use iPhone hardware acceleration for own GL?

Tags: iphone, hardware-acceleration

I wanna write my own OpenGL type graphics library. But I don't know how to access hardware acceleration on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware acceleration is exposed most directly by OpenGL — it's a very low-level library. Apple doesn't allow any lower level access and the hardware underneath isn't documented in any event.

Most third-party libraries are much higher level than OpenGL, talking in terms of scenes, objects, lights, etc, and all sit on top of it.